# Issue on Overriding Navbar Style in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to generate a custom nabar which looks like separate buttons  at [JSFIDDLE THIS LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/MKq2d/) as following image:

[image]

since I have two navbars in my page so I wrapped the first navbar inside a div wrapper called `.firstnav` as:

```
<div class="firstnav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-right" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header ">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md "  href="#">Teddy Bear Childcare</a>
  </div>
 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php?page_id=4">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="index.php?page_id=18">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
     <li class="nice"><a href="index.php?page_id=15">Programs</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="index.php?page_id=25">Testimonial</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
</div><!--/ End of navbar row-->
```

and for CSS I am trying to target the element by using `.firstnav >` which is not working for me , so far!. here is the code I have for CSS

```
.firstnav > .navbar-default, 
.firstnav > .navbar-right {
background-color:none !important;
border-color:none !important;
}
.firstnav > .navbar-nav > li {
float: left;
background: rgba(250,172,84,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(250,172,84,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(245,142,35,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#faac54', endColorstr='#f58e23', GradientType=0 );
margin-left:8px;
border:#fff 4px solid;
border-radius:25px;
color:white;
width:120px;
}
.firstnav >  .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;

  }
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule isn't working because you can't use `none` as a value for the `background-color` property; instead use the `background` shorthand (as what you're trying to override is a gradient anyway) - you also can't use `none` as a value  for `border-color` - to restore it to the initial value use `transparent`

```
.firstnav > .navbar-default, 
.firstnav > .navbar-right {
    background: none !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

The last two rules using `.firstnav > .navbar-nav` aren't working because `>` selects a **child** of a given element. `.navbar-nav` is not a child of `.firstnav` so these rules aren't applied.

Instead of `>` just use a [space](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors) between `.firstnav` & `.navbar-nav`: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/579/

```
.firstnav .navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
    background: rgba(250,172,84,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(250,172,84,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(245,142,35,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(250,172,84,1) 0%, rgba(245,142,35,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#faac54', endColorstr='#f58e23', GradientType=0 );
    margin-left:8px;
    border:#fff 4px solid;
    border-radius:25px;
    color:white;
    width:120px;
}

.firstnav .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Reconstuct's answer, the rules that were getting me were the    `box-shadow` rules

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
    ...
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
```

Set them both to `none` and no more annoying shadow in the background.